# MAPSTORE 2 start issue

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed mapstore2 through WAR file
But star command gives this error FAIL - Application at context path [/mapstore] could not be started
And log error is
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Error while creating file "/webapps" [90062-175])

owner of folder is tomcat.